# Excel: Multiply a number by a sequence of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel I want to create a sequence of numbers that goes like

435

870

1305

...

I tried typing the first few instances and then dragging the select thing that's supposed to apply a formula to a range of cells.  However, it just replaced the empty cells with repeats of the numbers I entered.  I also tried entering

```
= 1*$A$37
```

into the cell where `$A$37` contains my value, 435.  Then I tried again applying the formula, but again it did not predict the desired sequence.  So effectively I want to fill in

```
= i*$A$37
```

for `i` taking each value from 1 to whatever value I pick.  I'm sure I could generated a column of the numbers 1 through `n` but that seems like it needlessly eats up computing power, storage space, and screen space.  Any better solution?

Perhaps another way to ask the question is: Is there a function that merely iterates on each next column that it's applied to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `435` in A1

Enter the following formula in `A2`:

```
=A$1*ROW(A2)
```

And copy down

If you change the value in `A1`, the rest of the column will recalculate

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a column of numbers which are integer multiples of 435? As in 435x1, 435x2, 435x3,....435x(n)? The lazy way to do it is fill a column using the Fill, series feature up to (n).  Then in an adjacent column multiple each integer by 435 as in A1,A2,...A(n)*435.

Comment: Nothing wrong with his solution except that to get the number 2 is dependent on the command ROW(A2),  If you put in ROW(A3) you'll get a 3.  If you use the Fill, Series commands, you can specify the start number and specify the increment number, they can be any numbers you choose, 2.34, 4.3.  It just gives you more flexibility.